# Convert list of strings to list of 2-tuples of integers

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am currently have the following list: `['10 90', '10 -90', '100 45', '20 180']`. I am trying to convert the list of strings to 2-tuples full of integers, like `[(10, 90), (10, -90), (100, 45), (20, 180)]`.

I have tried using this code:

```
res = [tuple(map(int, sub.split(', '))) for sub in test_list]
```

However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10 90'
Command exited with non-zero status 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your own words, what does `sub.split(', ')` mean in your code? What values will `sub` have? Do you expect that to work? Why?

Comment: You could start by checking what `split` expects in the docs, and then realising that that separator is not what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each value of you list is like `'10 90'`,  2 **space-separated** numbers, they are not **comma-separated**, you you need to use `sub.split(' ')` or as the documentation states you have set no separatora and space will be used

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator

```
values = ['10 90', '10 -90', '100 45', '20 180']

res = [tuple(map(int, sub.split())) for sub in values]
print(res) # [(10, 90), (10, -90), (100, 45), (20, 180)]

res = [tuple(map(int, sub.split(" "))) for sub in values]
print(res) # [(10, 90), (10, -90), (100, 45), (20, 180)]
```

## [`Code Demo`](https://repl.it/repls/NegligibleHorizontalLocus)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst = ['10 90', '10 -90', '100 45', '20 180']
res = [tuple(map(int, x.split())) for x in lst]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[(10, 90), (10, -90), (100, 45), (20, 180)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
lst = ['10 90', '10 -90', '100 45', '20 180']
list_of_tuples = [tuple(int(x) for x in item.split()) for item in lst]
print(list_of_tuples)
```

Yielding

```
[(10, 90), (10, -90), (100, 45), (20, 180)]
```