# Convert list of strings to list of 2-tuples of integers (& Comma seperated in Tuple)

Tags: python, string, list, image, tuples

I need to convert a list of strings into a tuple.
My list look like this:

```
list = ['[11.  5.]', '[ 3. 16.]', '[ 0. 25.]', '[ 2. 40.]',
```

The list consists of tuples as a string (and unfortunately not as integer). Within the tuple there is no separation with a comma. Especially the combination with the comma makes me frustrated.

I found a similar solutions here, but somehow I can't get the commas into the tuples:
[Convert list of strings to list of 2-tuples of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62396478/convert-list-of-strings-to-list-of-2-tuples-of-integers/69064717#69064717)

Background: The list represents X and Y coordinates of pixels of an image, which I want to blacken. Like this (for the first row):

```
New_Image[list[0]] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to catch every integer from items of list, then form tuple from them as follows:

```
import re
ls= ['[11.  5.]', '[ 3. 16.]', '[ 0. 25.]', '[ 2. 40.]']

n = re.findall(r'\d+', ''.join(ls))
# -> ['11', '5', '3', '16', '0', '25', '2', '40']

res = [tuple(map(int, [n[i], n[i + 1]])) for i in range(0, len(n) - 1, 2)]
# -> [(11, 5), (3, 16), (0, 25), (2, 40)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the code works great. As an advantage over @Sarvesh Shetty's suggestion, it can even handle numbers in scientific notation (1.022e+03 and similar). This was not necessarily required, but still handy :-)

Thanks @ all =)

Answer (score 0):

I did a split on period "." on each pair.
if we take the first pair as example '[11.  5.]', I got "[11" (sub.split(".")[0])  in zero index and "5" in first index sub.split(".")[1].
I did a replace on square brackets "[" in zero index and converted the final output into tuple by adding round brackets on both ends.

```
    list = ['[11.  5.]', '[ 3. 16.]', '[ 0. 25.]', '[ 2. 40.]']
    
    new_list = [(int(sub.split(".")[0].replace("[","")),int(sub.split(".")[1]) ) for sub in list]
    
    print(new_list)
```